# how to take print out of some part of webpage using php?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to take print out of a webpage. I have written code for this and this work.The code is:

```
function printPage(){
        var tableData = '<table border="1">'+document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML+'</table>';
        var data = '<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button><br/>'+tableData;       
        myWindow=window.open('','','width=500,height=600');
        myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
        myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
        myWindow.screenX = 0;
        myWindow.screenY = 0;
        myWindow.document.write(data);
        myWindow.focus();
    };
```

But I don't want 'Print this page' button in print out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the @media css style method:

```
@media print {
/* css here to take out the "print this */
}
```

This will only apply the css styles when you print.

For example, you can give your button a class, say `class="printbtn"`

then:

```
@media print {

    .printbtn { display: none; }

}
```

Comment: Better to add the CSS with a stylesheet, but if you must do it with javascript as per your question, just add the following:

var css = myWindow.document.createElement('style');
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = "@media print { button { display: none; } }";
myWindow.document.body.appendChild(css);

Answer (score 0):

Simply use css for print defined area as....

```
 <style type="text/css">

    #printit { display: block; }

    @media print
    {
        #dont-printit { display: none; }
        #printit { display: block; }
    }
    </style>
```

and use `<div id="printit">` to print the part of web area......